# Intellij does not displays repos on auto complete drop down

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am new to maven and I wanted to try it out and I decided to choose Intellij IDEA IDE for this task.

I tried to follow few video tutorial to create simple spring project with maven. But I happen to notice that, while creating dependency on pom.xml file I could not get auto complete for packages that are present on .m2 directory inside my user home directory.

But I can see two item in autocomplete dropdown, one being the self project and other `maven-clean-plugin` for `artifactId`

I could not come up with any solution for this. May be this will not affect my development, but I got stuck with this issue and wanted to know what really happened.

I am more than happy to clear myself further if what I am asking is unclear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When auto-completing maven dependencies, IDEA uses an index it generates to know what dependencies are available. Go into *Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) >  Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories*. Your local repository should be listed. Select it and click `Update` for IDEA to update the index on it. It will take a bit of time. The progress will show on the center-right of the bottom status bar of the main IDEA window. If you use a repository manager, like Sonatype's Nexus, you should add it in the "Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs" section in the lower pane. Maven central will also likely be shown. You should update its index as well.

Click the `Help` button on that settings dialog for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped :) But I did two things one after another. Updated local repos and then updating remote repos. I am not sure which fixed the problem. But now I have plenty of suggestions in autocomplete dropdown :)

Comment: Is this "suggestions" feature available for gradle as well?